# Find the equation of the line tangent to the following curve at x=1. Write your answer in y=mx+b format.

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the line tangent to the following curve at $x=1$. Write your answer in $y=mx+b$ format. The curve is defined by    $y=2x^2+6x-4.$
 Please help with step by step instructions...I am having trouble with this...

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Find the slope of the tangent to the curve $y=2x^2+6x−4.$.
$$m=\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{d}{dx}(2x^2+6x−4)=4x+6.$$
At $x=1$ the slope is $m=4+6=10$.

**Step 2**: Write the equation of the tangent in the form $y=mx+c$.
$$y=10x+c \tag{1}$$
**Step 4**: Find $c$.
To find $c$ notice that the intersection point of the tangent with the curve is known. The intersection point has $x$ coordinate $1$ and y coordinate $y=2(1)^2+6\cdot 1-4=4$. So we know that the point $(1,4)$ lie on the tangent.
   We can find $c$ now. For this substitute $x=1$ and $y=4$ in the eqation 1.
$$4=10(1)+c \implies \ c=-6$$.
**Step 5**: Write down the answer, that is the equation of the tangent.
$$y=10x-6$$

Comment: @Seth I am doing his homework because homework-like questions are on-topic here. It is the question which should be closed at the first place - if not then let me do his homework.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent line must pass through the point $(1,4)$, so it has the form
$$
y-4=m(x-1)
$$
or
$$
y=mx-m+4.
$$
Substitute in the equation of the parabola; the discriminant of the resulting equation must be zero.